# ANSI C - Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, ansi-c

I am using ANSI C and getting "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault." for my below code when I run it. Compiling is fine. No error there.

```
#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 1024
#define DELIMITER ","
#define TICKET_NAME_LEN 40
#define TICKET_ZONE_LEN 10

struct stock_data 
{
    char ticket_name[TICKET_NAME_LEN+1];
    char ticket_type;
    char ticket_zone[TICKET_ZONE_LEN+1];
    unsigned int ticket_price;
    unsigned int stock_level;
};

typedef struct stock_node 
{
    struct stock_data * data;
    struct stock_node * next_node;
} stock_node;

char temp_line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
char *token;
int i, count = 0;

stock_node * snode = NULL;
struct stock_data * sdata = NULL;

FILE *stock_file = fopen( stockfile, "r" );

while (fgets(temp_line, MAX_LINE_SIZE, stock_file) != NULL) {

  token = strtok (temp_line, DELIMITER);
  count++;

  snode = (stock_node *) realloc(snode, count * sizeof(stock_node));
  if (snode == NULL) { abort(); }  

  snode->data = (struct stock_data *) malloc(sizeof(struct stock_data));
  if (snode->data == NULL) { abort(); }  

  i = 1;

 while(token != NULL) {
     switch(i) {
        case 1:
           strcpy(snode[count - 1].data->ticket_name, token);
           break;
        case 2:
           snode[count - 1].data->ticket_type = token[0];
           break;
        case 3:
           strcpy(snode[count - 1].data->ticket_zone, token);
           break;
        case 4:
           snode[count - 1].data->ticket_price = atoi(token);
           break;
        case 5:
           snode[count - 1].data->stock_level = atoi(token);
           break;                                                            
     }

     token = strtok (NULL, DELIMITER);
     i++;
  }
}
```

I used the **gdb tool** to debug it and I found that I get the error for below lines: (For any of them. I tried with disabling them one by one and each of them caused the segfault error.)

**strcpy(snode[count - 1].data->ticket_name, token); 

snode[count - 1].data->ticket_type = token[0]; 

strcpy(snode[count - 1].data->ticket_zone, token); 

snode[count - 1].data->ticket_price = atoi(token); 

snode[count - 1].data->stock_level = atoi(token);**

Comment: I'm just not sure right now and to silly to look it up. So: is `realloc ()` without `malloc()` valid?

Comment: I believe stock_node * snode = NULL; does the job for malloc()

Comment: @Zaibis Nop, snode is initialized to NULL

Comment: @Zaibis realloc(NULL,n) is equivalent to malloc(n) i guess.

Comment: 7.22.3.5
If ptr is a null pointer, the realloc function behaves like the malloc function for the speciﬁed size.

Comment: ah yeah now i remember, your right jester.

Comment: by the way, as you are in c, remove the cast of return value of malloc ;)

Comment: what does `strlen(token);` put out? `token`, AFAIKT, could be longer than `TICKET_NAME_LEN`, couldn't it? what if you replaced `strcpy` with `strncpy`? do you still get the segfaults then?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem data is not more/longer than defined values

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would have really helped you and the those trying to figure out what the problem is. There is no `main`, we don't know what headers you are including, if someone wants to plug this into an [online compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator) they also need to simulate the file input etc...

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour there are multiple files involve. I just wanted to simplify the code. I don't think `segfault` is related with headers at all. So that's why I didn't add them.

Comment: @Ozgur It is just good practice to provide a SSCCE it requires more work from you but part of the point is that in many cases the act of producing the SSCCE actually leads to a solution. In fact not including a SSCCE is a [reason put a question on hold](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it looks like `snode[count - 1].data` is never initialized. Only the first index `snode[0].data` is allocated

I think you should replace

```
snode->data = (struct stock_data *) malloc(sizeof(struct stock_data));
if (snode->data == NULL) { abort(); }
```

By

```
snode[count - 1].data = (struct stock_data *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct stock_data));
if (snode[count - 1].data == NULL) { abort(); }
```

Comment: `count` is 1 and it increases. that's why I put `count-1` to start from 0 for `snode[0]`

Comment: Shafik your right, but he is right anyway, the data member is never initialised, so at least it is not valid to use string operations on it, as ou can't be sure there is any `'\0'`

Comment: @Zaibis how can I initialize it?

Comment: Use `memset()` ;) Or as in this answer `calloc()` is returning 0 initalised memory, thats allso a option (its even the better one)

Comment: @Zaibis calloc is better :-)

Comment: @benjarobin if I use your suggestion I get `error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘stock_node’)` for the line `if (snode[count - 1]->data == NULL) { abort(); } `

Comment: @benjarobin thats what I wanted to say (does it sound different?) It is better, as `calloc()` is using idle time to prepare memory for usage of `calloc()` as memset just causes the processor to set it.

Comment: `strcpy()` is okay to use even if the destination doesn't have a null-terminated string.

Comment: @MichaelBrennan This is true, but it is a more cleaner code to get already initialized memory with calloc.

Comment: @benjarobin yep. it worked. Thank you and Thanks to Zaibis as well.